# Comparing two elements textContent not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 elements with different length I need to compare if elements textContent are equal but code is not working maybe my coding logic is incorrect?

I need to output every hours which is equal to times textContent.

> error: js.js:400 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined

```
const hours = document.querySelectorAll('.user-hours');
const times = document.querySelectorAll('.user-times');

for(let a = 0; a < hours.length; a++){

    for(let b = 0; times.length; b++){
        if (hours[a].textContent == times[b].textContent) {
            console.log(hours[a].textContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to match every `hours` with all the `times`? Clarify your required output with valid input data.

Comment: i need to outoput every hours wich is equal to times textContent

Comment: Your inner loop is either not executed at all or it will run "forever" (= until `times[b]` is `undefined`) -> `; times.length;` is missing a `b < `

Comment: Attach your HTML code also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's first turn the elements into the things we want to compare...

```
const hoursEls = document.querySelectorAll('.user-hours');
const timesEls = document.querySelectorAll('.user-times');

const hours = hoursEls.map(e => e.textContent);
const times = timesEls.map(e => e.textContent);
```

I understand the question to say: which hours elements' textContents are present in the times elements' textContents? That's a sort of reduce on the `hours` array

```
const hoursWeWant = hours.reduce((acc, hour, index) => {
  if (times.includes(hour)) acc.push(hoursEls[index]);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

The body of that loop says, if hours text matches the criterion, place the hours DOM element of the same index into the result.

Comment: Why is a `TypeError` the accepted answer?

Comment: And why the extra step with `indexes.map()`? Why don't you get the elements in the `.reduce()`

Comment: Edited to save one loop through the elements at the expense of some readability for new programmers.